# Passing a variable into a function and changing its global value

Tags: c

I am trying to pass a variable into a function and change its global value but it does not work. Here is the simplified code:

```
int main()
{
   int *Num = malloc (sizeof (int));
   ChangeValue(&Num);
   printf("Number is %i\n", Num);
}


int ChangeValue(int *temp)
{
   *temp = 10
}
```

The error message is:

```
        expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int **'
```

I tried to change the function to   int ChangeValue(int **temp)   but received the following error:

```
        warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Any suggestions?` Read the error message. It's pretty clear...

Comment: @John3136 Very little about C is clear when you're starting out.

Answer (score 3):

`int *Num` means `Num` is of type `int *`. Since it's already an integer pointer, there's no need to take its address again when you pass it to your function that takes an `int *`.

```
ChangeValue(Num);
```

OTOH, since it is a pointer you will have to dereference it to use it as an integer, like with `printf`.

```
printf("Number is %i\n", *Num);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did what you just said and the code worked. However, I received two warning messages.
warning: implicit declaration of function 'ChangeValue'
warning: conflicting types for 'ChangeValue'

Comment: @AfshinAhmadi C has to know the signature for a function before you use it. Otherwise it will guess (that's the implicit warning), usually incorrectly, and get confused when it finally sees the function and it doesn't match its guess. Do this by either moving ChangeValue() before main() or declare the prototype of ChangeValue() before main(). I'd suggest the former, it's simpler and there's less duplication.

Answer (score 2):

Variable `Num` is a pointer to an int (`int*`). Function `ChangeValue(int*)` takes a pointer to an int (`int*`). However, you are passing a pointer to `Num` (`int**`) to it.

Short answer: remove `&` before `Num` in `ChangeValue(&Num);`

Long answer: You seem to have a problem understanding how pointers work, you might want to read more about this before going further.

Comment: Thank you very much, Tommalla. You are right, I am still new in C programming.